# How to return values to function from Windows Form?

Tags: vb.net, selenium, unit-testing

I'm trying to return a couple values from a form to a function I'm running in a module called from the init method of a test class. When I run the code, the values aren't captured from the form. The intent is to use those values in some unit tests run with selenium.

I've tried using public properties to get the values out and I've tried creating a public function in the form to do the same. The form is opened as a dialog, the user enters text in a textbox, and once the Done button is clicked the dialog result is set to OK.

```
<TestClass()> Public Class Tests
    <ClassInitialize()> Public Shared Sub Setup()
        TestModule.DoSomething()        
    End Sub
End Class



Public Module TestModule
    Private val As String

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        Dim str As String
        Dim form As New MyForm.Form1
        form.ShowDialog()
        str = form.ReturnVal
    End Sub
End Module



Public Class Form1
    Private rval As String

    Private Sub btnDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDone.Click
        ReturnVal = textbox.Text
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    End Sub

    Public Property ReturnVal() As String
        Get
            return rval
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            rval = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: In `Form1`, declare a public variable which will be set from the function using `Form1.variableName = value`. And there is no need to create a new instance of the form each time the `DoSomething` method is called simply use the default `Form1`.

Comment: Where are you testing the value of `str`?

Comment: @HardCode In this example, I'm just trying to get the value. I can verify the string is not empty in ReturnVal's Set.